# Extract feature points from mouth with EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv, feature-detection

I am looking to extract the feature points from the mouth I have detected. At the moment, I am using the DetectMultiScale() function from EmguCV to draw a rectangle around the mouth. It works fine but I need to get the positions of at least 4 points from the mouth : the left and the right extremity and the middle of the bottom and top lips.

Is there any function I can use directly with EmguCV or do I have to use another library to extract those points ? In the second case, which library would you recommend ?